# load child objects after session closed

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

I want to load an objects sub after session closed, anyway to do that?

```
using (var session = NHibernateHelper<T>.OpenSession())
{
    Foo = session.CreateCriteria(Foo).List<Foo>();
}

using (var session = NHibernateHelper<T>.OpenSession())
{
     Foo.Children.Load();
}


public static void Load<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
     //load foo with Children
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can here profit from NHibernate native support for working with detached objects

#### [19.1.4. Initializing collections and proxies](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-initialization)

> ...
>   You may also attach a previously loaded object to a new ISession with **`Merge()`** or **`Lock()`** before accessing **uninitialized collections** (or other proxies). No, NHibernate does not, and certainly should not do this automatically, since it would introduce ad hoc transaction semantics!
>   ...

The adjusted **Load()** method would look like this:

```
public static TEntity LoadCollection<TEntity, TItem>(
        this TEntity entity, 
        Func<TEntity, IList<TItem>> listGetter)
    where TEntity : class
{
    using (var session = NHibernateHelper<T>.OpenSession())
    {
        // here we get brand new - connected - instance of TEntity
        TEntity reAttached = session.Merge<TEntity>(entity);

        NHibernate.NHibernateUtil
            .Initialize(listGetter.Invoke(reAttached));

        return reAttached;
    }
}
```

And the calling side:

```
using (var session = NHibernateHelper<T>.OpenSession())
{
    IList<Foo> foos = session.CreateCriteria<Foo>()
            ...
            .List<Contact>();
}

Foo foo = foos.First();

// here we get merged instance with initiated
foo =  foo.LoadCollection(f => f.SomeCollection);
```

*NOTE: It really depends why we need that. Merging will need to change the reference (old detached object will be lost).

Sometimes could be enough (or even better) to just load collection as `IList<TItem>` directly, via session, using Where `ParentId = current.ID`... just an idea...*

Comment: Sir, if this could help to get someone like you into NHibernate... that's amazing. Enjoy NHibernate ;)